# Finding asymptotic variance of MLE using Fisher information - comprehension of steps

Tags: probability, statistics, maximum-likelihood

I'm working on finding the asymptotic variance of an MLE using Fisher's information.

The distribution is a Pareto distribution with density function $f(x|x_0, \theta) = \theta \cdot x^{\theta}_0 \cdot x^{-\theta - 1}$.

There are two steps I don't get, namely step 3 and 5.

(step 1) We have that

$1 = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f(x|x_0, \theta)$

(Step 2) We take derrivative wrt $\theta$:

$0 = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{\partial f(x|x_0, \theta)}{\partial \theta} dx$

(**Step 3**) We can (according to my textbook) write the above as:

$0 = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{\partial f(x|x_0, \theta)/\partial \theta }{f(x|x_0,\theta)} f(x|x_0,\theta) dx$

(Step 4) This can again be written as an expectation:

$E[\frac{\partial \log f(x|x_0,\theta)}{\partial \theta}] = 0$

(**Step 5**) According to my textbook we can differentiate again and get:

$0 = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{\partial^2 \log f(x|x_0, \theta)}{\partial \theta^2} f(x|x_0, \theta) dx + \int^{\infty}_{- \infty} \frac{\partial \log f(x|x_0,\theta)}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial \log f(x|x_0,\theta)}{\partial \theta} f(x|x_0, \theta) dx$

I can't figure if I have just stared at these steps for too long, or if there is something fundamental about differentiation and integration I have missed.

I would be very grateful if someone could explain the steps 3 and 5 to me in layman's manner?

(Textbook is Hogg & Craig "introduction to mathematical statistics").

Comment: To go from Step #2 to Step #3, multiply and divide by $f(x|x_0,\theta)$. To see step #5, differentiate the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\partial \log f(x|x_0,\theta)}{\partial \theta}f(x|x_0,\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta$ from Step #4 with respect to $\theta$ and use product rule.

Answer (score 2):

Many of your calculations are redundant. Assuming $x_0$ as a known parameter and considering the MLE of $\theta$

First observe that,

$$\sqrt{nI_X(\theta)}\left[\hat{\theta}_{ML}-\theta   \right]\xrightarrow{\mathcal{L}}N(0;1)$$

Thus its variance is

$$\frac{1}{nI_X(\theta)}$$

Where

$$nI_X(\theta)=-n\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\log f(x|\theta)   \right]$$

Now let's focus on the log density

$$\log f(x|\theta)=\log \theta+\theta\log x_0-\theta \log x-\log x$$

It is self evident that, without many efforts, the only addend that will be not zero after derivating 2 times is $\log \theta$

Thus

$$nI_X(\theta)=\frac{n}{\theta^2}$$

giving the asymptotic requested variance as

$$\frac{\theta^2}{n}$$

Comment: THank you for your reply. I really appreciate the effort. However, it is a bit over my head atm lol. What does the first step mean?

Comment: @bestmate21: skip it. It is just the theorem stating that MLE's distribution is asimptotically normal. Observe and understand how easy is to derive Fisher's information